# Notify Js displaying notification at the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, notify

I am using notify.js plugin to display notification in my website.

```
https://notifyjs.com/
```

As per the documentation, it says by default the notification will be displayed in the top right corner.
Somehow the notification is getting displayed at the bottom.
[image]

When going through the code in notify.js its appending the div element at the end of the body.So I changed it to prepend but the notification is still getting displayed at the bottom.

```
anchor.css(css).addClass(pluginClassName + "-corner");
$("body").append(anchor);
```

Any reason why this is happening? Any pointers where I should debug?
The code I am using to notify is :

```
$.notify("Name cannot be empty!","error");
```

Comment: Take a look at the css classes of notify.js containers. You may be overwriting a property like `position: absolute;` to `position: relative;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I could see, when the plugin is instanciated a DOM element is appended to the body:

```
<div class="notifyjs-corner" style="top: 0px; right: 0px;"></div>
```

All notifications are created inside this DOM element.

The original definition for the rule ***notifyjs-corner*** is:

```
.notifyjs-corner {
    position: fixed;
    margin: 5px;
    z-index: 1050;
}
```

You should check if by accident, you overwrite the CSS rule.

Try to find and inspect that DOM element.

Answer (score 2):

The following approach by re-defining the default setup for page:

```
$.notify.defaults({globalPosition: 'top left'})
```

may help in this case.